How can I make it so that material keyframes appear in the graph editor?
I have been trying for a while how to get this material animation working but I can't seem to figure out how to get my keyframes to show up in the graph editor. They appear in the Dope Sheet editor but they don't appear in the graph editor.
I posted some screenshots to show what I mean.
AS you can see, the plane with the material applied is selected as well. But still, no keyframes.

